# How do view Flickr.com using the OLD style, consistently & automatically?

Tags: flickr

I know there is a "secret" way to display pages from Flickr.com in the old style -- which the majority of old users preferred.

How do I consistently and automatically view pages  in this style?

Answer (score 2):

1. Install ["Redirector" Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/pajiegeliagebegjdhebejdlknciafen)
2. Go to `chrome://extensions`, and find Redirector, and click options.
3. Create a new redirect.

   - From: `(https://www.flickr.com/photos/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/*)$`
   - To:   `$1?details=1`

Comment: Psuedo-related:

If you want to click facebook links in forwarded emails from other users, without getting logged out and having to log in again, add this one:



FROM: (.*)(facebook.com)(.*)(&mid=.*)  TO: $1$2$3 ..... Obviously if you do not have access to the post, you'll be directed to nothing. But my wife & I share facebook emails, and click each other's "View post" links daily, so this has saved us 5 logins a day, each, for a good year now.